# Filter out null fields in snakeyaml

Tags: null, snakeyaml

I am using snakeyaml to print my object in a YAML file. There are some fields which could be null. 
How can I prevent these field, when they are null from being printed in the file?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After some research I have finally found the solution. One needs to change how null fields have to be represented in Representer
Here is the code

```
Representer representer = new Representer() {
    @Override
    protected NodeTuple representJavaBeanProperty(Object javaBean, Property property, Object propertyValue,Tag customTag) {
        // if value of property is null, ignore it.
        if (propertyValue == null) {
            return null;
        }  
        else {
            return super.representJavaBeanProperty(javaBean, property, propertyValue, customTag);
        }
    }
};
String s = new Yaml(representer).dump(obj)
```

Comment: Note: you can use the representer like this: `Yaml yaml = new Yaml(representer, options);`